# How to get column data types from pymssql?

Tags: python, pymssql, python-db-api

According to the Python DB API, one of the fields in cursor.description returns a type_code; however these are always numbers. How do I convert from type_code (eg. 1) to a data type (eg. TEXT)?

Answer (score 4):

The numbers appear to correspond to the Python data type of the items in the row tuple(s) returned by the Cursor object, namely:

1 : STRING type
2 : BINARY type
3 : NUMBER type
4 : DATETIME type
5 : ROWID type

(ref: [Type Objects and Constructors](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#type-objects-and-constructors))

Comment: is there a built in enum or something i can use to map these datatypes? similar to [MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE-module.html)

Comment: Note that type 3 "NUMBER" can be either an integer or a floating point value.

When I have a value type of DECIMAL in the result the type code returned is 5.